# Regular expressions: inserting a word and NOT replacing the found key

Tags: regex

I have a list of items, such as:

```
this_thing.ety
other-stuff.ety
34-pairings.ety
```

I want to do this:
"At the beginning of every line, insert "images/"
so the result of search/replace with reg exp would yield:

```
images/this_thing.ety
images/other-stuff.ety
images/34-pairings.ety
```

I am using:

```
 ^.
```

as my anchor to find the beginning of each line but everything I've tried to add "images/" has resulted in actually replacing that first character. I am using Notepad ++, but can use anything.

I thought using ${foo} was on the right track but I'm missing something here.

Comment: In sublime I can use the regex `^` by itself and it will insert before the first character

Comment: ^- that, or enclose your expression (in this case .) in parenthesis like this: ^(.), and replace with images/\1. This will work with more complex expressions in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regex `^.`is matching begin of line and a character. If you replace this by 'image', first character, which matched, will be replaced. Empty line wont have 'image' but stay identical (they don't match `^.`)

Just use `^` as regexp for begin of line

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I know many posted the same, but I hit this one first. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

. is the any character symbol, but can only account for one character. You will want to use ^..*$ or ^.+$ if your version of regex allows so that every line that contains at least one character will be fully replaced. With replace, it would look like this

```
s/^(.+)$/images\/\1/
```

where the \1 re-inserts the part in parenthesis in the regex.  In older versions of regex, try

```
s/^^\(..*\)$/\1/
```